# how to modify the media controller of video view

Tags: android

I want to modify the media controller of video view and want to place the controller at the bottom of videoview instead of at the bottom of layout(as shown in image )
[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un25n.jpg)

Here's my code

```
  vid = findViewById(R.id.vidview);
        mc = new MediaController(this);
        String httpLiveUrl = "http://livestream.in:1010/live/vido.m3u8";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl);
        vid.setVideoURI(uri);
        vid.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.setAnchorView(vid);
        //vid.requestFocus();
        vid.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Only Solution I think so is that to convert your video view in a frame Layout as shown below :

```
<Frame Layout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

//use your own constraints
        app:layout_constraint Bottom_bottom``="parent"
        app:layout_constraint Left_leftover="parent"
        app:layout_constraint Right_forthright="parent"
        app:layout_constraint Top_rooftop="parent">

```
    <Video View
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</Frame Layout>
```